# Get contents of a specific file in google drive API with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-api-js-client

I have found many posts on how to retrieve the contents of a `.txt` file from the google drive with their API. I have tried using this:

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    var data = drive.files.get({
        fileId: file_id,
        alt: "media"
    });
    data.execute(function(response){
        console.log(reponse)
    })
```

My error

```
data.execute(function(response){
     ^

TypeError: data.execute is not a function
```

and also `data.then` instead of `data.execute` each time there is an error that I research and find no resolution to it. Could someone please give me an updated version of how to get the contents of a file from the file id? As I think the previous answers are outdated somewhat.

Sorry if this is pretty obvious. I relatively new to javascript and apis in general. So this would help me out a lot as it's the final stretch before I finish my program :)

Thanks, Mathias

Comment: Could you add an error in the question?

Comment: Sorry. I've added it now, hopefully that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run 'drive.files.get' for google drive API you receive a promise, and to get data you have to use then on it. This is how it works:

```
  const filePath = `give_path_tosave_file`;
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
  let progress = 0;

  drive.files.get(
    { fileId, alt: 'media' },
    { responseType: 'stream' }
  ).then(res => {
    res.data
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Done downloading file.');
      })  
      .on('error', err => {
        console.error('Error downloading file.');
      })  
      .on('data', d => {
        d+='';
        console.log(d);
        //data will be here
        // pipe it to write stream
        }   
      })  
      .pipe(dest);
  });
```

If above solution doesn't work, you can use this one. It is on official google website for doing the same:

```
var fileId = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/filename.txt');
drive.files.export({
  fileId: fileId,
  mimeType: 'application/txt'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

For more info, you should check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#node.js_1).

Also, the below method will return all the files which you have access to in drive.

```
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const files = res.data.files;
  if (files.length) {
  files.map((file) => {
    console.log(file);
  });
  } else {
    console.log('No files found');
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there no way to just get the data of the google drive file, rather than having to download it first?

Comment: Yes, you can get it too. Let me add it to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sure I will reuse this code in lots of my node programs

Comment: Which is the one that returns the contents of a specific file? If you haven't added it yet then my mistake

Comment: The above two code with fileID gives you to the speific file content and it is not necessary to use writeStream to save it, you can console the data.

Comment: sure, you can check it and I have also added the official google link which can help you to achieve this using Node.js

Comment: I have implimented your code and data is being outputted. I went through all the object attributes but cannot find the contents of my file. Just several values assigned to null, buffer and false.

Comment: Do you have proper authentication setup for your Google DRIVE? Does it throw any error?

Comment: No error. my auth works fine as I can write and upload files fine. it just returns an object called PassThrough with about 100 values in it

Comment: its a stream object which you can convert., I have updated the code. This is a stream data you just need to convert it to readble form.

Comment: Amazing! Work's perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and patience

Comment: Just another quick question. How would i go about returning d outside of the function as right now it returns undefined. I understand if you need to move on, you've helped more than enough already

Comment: It seems to return the value before the `res.data.on` finishes defining the variable. Anyway for it to wait till the async function is finished before returning a value?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions offered here do not handle concurrency correctly. The problem is that the functions will end before the stream of data for the file will end. Here is a solution where the function will end after the file data stream will be consumed:

```
import { google } from "googleapis"

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT("", undefined, "",
  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
)
const googleDrive = google.drive("v3")

async function downloadFile(fileId: string): Promise<Buffer> {
  await jwtClient.authorize()
  const res = await googleDrive.files.get(
    { fileId, alt: "media", auth: jwtClient },
    { responseType: "stream" }
  )

  const buffers: any[] = []
  await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    res.data
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log(`End of reading the file`)
        resolve()
      })
      .on("error", err => {
        reject(`Cannot create file ${err}`)
      })
      .on("data", chunk => {
        buffers.push(chunk)
      })
  })

  console.log(`End of the function`)
  return Buffer.concat(buffers)
}
```

The message `End of reading the file` will be printed before the message `End of the function` will be printed.